# How to change Date Format in DOCman 2.0 RC 1

Tags: joomla, module, date-format

How can I change date format in joomla module named DOCman?

Currently it look like:
"Wednesday, 25 September 2013"

and i want something like this: 
"25-09-2013"

Thanks in advance.

ps: I tried this but it is for older version
http://www.alexwalker.co.uk/joomla-solutions/6-how-to-change-date-format-in-docman

Comment: DOCman is commercial extension therefore you should always contact the developers of the extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last time I checked with the developers of DOCman about this, this was not possible due to a bug. It is due to be fixed for RC2.

Answer (score 1):

Found it!

it's located in: ...\components\com_docman\views\list\tmpl\table.php

line number: 176

Change to:

```
<?= @date(array('date' => $document->publish_date, 'format' => '%d.%m.%Y (%H:%M:%S)' )); ?>
```

Result:

25.09.2013 (23:42:53)

:)